# Does it make sense to sum two Choi operators?

Tags: quantum-state, quantum-operation

I am very new to the theory of the Choi representation of quantum processes and I am learning it all by myself from research papers (especially this https://arxiv.org/abs/1111.6950) as I didn't find any quantum info book describing it. I was wondering if given two Choi operators $\Lambda_1$, $\Lambda_2$, it was possible to construct a new Choi operator $\Lambda$ as a convex linear combination of the two. i.e.  $\Lambda = (1-a)\Lambda_1 +  a \Lambda_2$ as one would do with the states $(1-a)\rho_1 +  a \rho_2$. If it is possible to what process $\Lambda$ would correspond?

Comment: the mapping between a channel and its Choi is linear, therefore linear combinations of Chois give the Choi corresponding to the associated linear combination of maps

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The one from channels to Choi state is a linear isomorphism. This means that whatever is valid for one set, is valid from the other. Practically, besides how we write it down, there is no mathematical difference at all between a channel and its Choi state, they are the same mathematical object. Hence, it shouldn't be surprising that the convex combination of a bunch of Choi states corresponds to che Choi state of the convex combination of the corresponding channels, neverthess let's write it down explicitely, if

$$ \Lambda_i =\mathbb 1_A\otimes\mathcal E_B^i |\Omega\rangle_{AB}$$

where $|\Omega\rangle_{AB}$ is the unnormalized maximally entangled state, then

$$ \sum_{i}p_i \Lambda_i=\sum_{i}p_i\mathbb 1_A\otimes \mathcal E_B^i|\Omega\rangle_{AB}=\mathbb 1_A\otimes\left(\sum_{i}p_i \mathcal E_B^i\right) |\Omega\rangle_{AB}$$

so you can see that the linear combination $\sum_{i}p_i \Lambda_i$ is the Choi state of the map $\sum_{i}p_i \mathcal E_B^i$. It remains to see whether this map is a channel. It is trace preserving because

$$\mathrm{Tr} \left(\sum_{i}p_i \mathcal E_B^i(\rho)\right)=\sum_i p_i=1$$

and completely positive because a sum of CP maps is CP.

Conversely it is clear that if you take a convex combination of channel, the corresponding Choi state is the convex combination of the Choi states of the individual channels.

Answer (score 2):

Any quantum channel, which of course has a Choi-representation, has a Kraus operator representation too. Meaning, any action of a channel can be described by a set of [Kraus Operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_operation).

Let $\Lambda_1$ and $\Lambda_2$ be described as (on some density operator $\rho$):

$$
\Lambda_1 (\rho) = \sum_i E_i \rho E_i^\dagger, \\\Lambda_2 (\rho) = \sum_j F_j \rho F_j^\dagger.
$$

Then, you can see that a convex combination of these two channels would be another channel with action as:

$$
\Lambda(\rho) = (1 - a) \Lambda_1(\rho) +  a \Lambda_2(\rho) = (1 - a) \sum_i E_i \rho E_i^\dagger + a\sum_j F_j \rho F_j^\dagger
$$

Comment: I'm not sure this really addresses what the OP was asking. They were asking if you take a convex combination at the level of the Choi matrices, does this correspond to something at the level of channels? Indeed it does correspond to a convex combination of channels but only because we have an isomorphism between the two objects and so we preserve the linear structure of their respective spaces.

Comment: Yes, I am sorry. I think I get your answer, although your equation is not very clear. On one side there is a matrix, on the other there is an operator. I think it's now clear to me what a sum of Chois will give

Comment: I see, you are right, Rammus... I just thought it may be clearer if instead of channels, we show it with the Kraus operators, the linearity is more visible. Thanks for the point...